# How to make a menu of options with words or phrases without using a letter or number?

Tags: switch-statement, case

[image]

[image]

```
printf("What account do you need ?\n");
scanf("%s", &youtube, &google);

if(strcmp(youtube, "youtube") == 0) {   
    printf("youtube password\n");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    exit(0);
}

if(strcmp(google, "google") == 0) {
    printf("google password ");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    exit(0);
}

if(strcmp(reddit, "reddit") == 0) { 
    printf("reddit password ");
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    exit(0);        
}
```